# Radio button in a Tkinter menu

Tags: python, tkinter

**goal**

Understanding how a radiobutton in a Tkinter menu works

**code**

I have a radio button inside the options menu as so:

```
v = BooleanVar()

v.set(True)

options.add_radiobutton(label="change pop up", command =togglePopUp,variable=v,onvalue=True,offvalue=False)
```

`togglePopUp` is a function that changes the value of variable `v` from `True` to `False` or vice versa. Main window is already opened and this menu will be added later to the window. This is just the fragment of code that is related to the radiobutton.

**Question**

Now my question is when I press the radiobutton (after running the code) will the value of the variable be changed or will the function togglePopUp be called? If the function will be called then what will happen to the status of the radiobutton? will the status of the radiobutton be updated instantly or will there be a delay?

**research**

I read about the radiobutton and the Boolean variable from the Tkinter book at effbot.org. But I was not convinced about how it worked. I tried a program but I am not getting the output that I essentially want. So I decided to understand how it works at a deeper level.

**specs** python 2.7 Tkinter 8.5
Linux Mint 14

Comment: You should simply try it and observe what happens.

Comment: i did but could not reeally understand what was going on inside!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both actions will occur. When you click on a radiobutton, first the variable will change its value, and after that the event handler passed as `command` option is called if present.

Also your example would not work, since `add_radiobutton` doesn't allow the `onvalue` and `offvalue` options - only `value`.

Comment: i did not understand hat you are saying. what is the normal behavior of the widget?? will it change the variable or not??

Comment: @IcyFlame By normal behaviour I meant the default action that occurs - in this case, changing the value of the variable when the widget is clicked. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: sorry. @ A Rodas. i mixed up a radio button and a check button!! sorry!!